# Aerosol products in space

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, microgravity, safety

I am assuming aerosol products are not used inside the living environment of a spacecraft while it is microgravity.  Is that correct, or are there examples of such products being used while an individual or crew are in microgravity?

Comment: The same sources I used in [this answer about WD-40](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38885/26446) returned nothing about aerosols.  I don't recall having read about them anywhere else.  I would expect them difficult to control and possibly fouling the cabin air.

Comment: I am unaware of any aerosol cans ever being carried on Shuttle. No idea how to confirm this though.

Comment: Given that such products would have undoubtedly been included in the following study, I have to conclude that they are not allowed on the ISS: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150000882.pdf

Comment: Unless you count the laser printers mentioned in that study.

Comment: @called2voyage That link is great if for no other reason than the discussion of a "personal cloud" lol