# Is the mass of paint relevant in rocket design?

Tags: rockets, design, mass

(Prompted by [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38914/10509)):

Do the designers of large rockets<sup>*</sup> (have to) take the mass of the exterior paint into account?

If so, do we have examples of actual design changes/decisions based on this (and not on other paint properties like color/heat exchange)?

<sup>* Saturn 5, the larger Deltas, Falcons, ...</sup>

Comment: I remember looking through the documentation for a Cessna 152 (two seat flight trainer) and marvelling at the fact that, not only did they list the weight and center of gravity for the exterior paint, but they also broke it down into separate numbers for the white base coat and for the color stripe.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Nothing too surprising about that. Aircraft engine manufacturers usually have a "weights department" with a team of specialist engineers whose sole job is to keep track of mass and CG position, literally down to the last nut, bolt, and washer. This often involves physically weighing parts - the "weight calculations" in CAD software are notoriously inaccurate.

Comment: Listing the center of gravity of the surface paint in the shape following the aircraft surface separately is genuinely nerdy. [Imagining the dried paint as separate object in weightlessness]

Comment: And while we are at it: if there is more than one color used, the center of gravity changes when the viscosity of a paint is changed, nice...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

When the shuttle External Tank stopped being painted white, the [weight savings](https://www.space.com/2282-columbias-white-external-fuel-tanks.html) was ~600 lbs (~270 kg).

This is not a tremendous amount from a vehicle standpoint, but the tank was carried almost to orbit, so weight shaved off it was a direct addition to payload capability, and that amount could be significant for payloads.

Comment: I never looked at it from that direction: weight saved = extra payload possible given the same design

Comment: @JanDoggen don't know about other vehicles, but shuttle's propellant tanks were always filled to the same point, so on a given mission, a weight savings either meant more weight for payloads or performance margin.

Comment: Cool, so the crew could stand to gain 38 kg each and still be within mission parameters.

Comment: Why was it painted in the first place then?

Comment: I prefer "over a quarter tonne" -- or in American "more than a fourth of a metric ton"

Comment: @JCRM I'm a "slug" man myself but I reluctantly used the numbers in the source :) https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/85077483/real-engineers-use-slugs.jpg

Answer (score 20):

WD-40 was designed to protect the Atlas rocket from rust and corrosion. The skin of the Atlas was so thin, to save weight, that from the moment it was welded together it always had to be pressurized so it wouldn't collapse in on itself. It needed that protectant because it was unpainted, to save weight.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(rocket_family)#SM-65_Atlas_missile

Comment: But why needed tanks made from stainless steel protection against rusting? Was it a low quality stainless steel not immune to rust?

Comment: Good question! I had never seen the alloy mentioned. Looking around... Greg Smith tells us that it's 301, which is stronger but less corrosion-resistant than 304. But I don't know what his authority is. Jeff Deem also mentions the corrosiveness of sea air.
https://groups.io/g/cia-rocketry/topic/mercury_atlas_rocket/29059103?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,29059103

Comment: My 1964 *Spacecraft and Boosters* book agrees that its' "a special cold-rolled austenitic steel (A1S1 grade 301) (p.219)

Comment: Austenitic stainless steel is what they make stainless cookware from, stuff that is expected to stand up to boiling brine or vinegar - though 304 seems to be preferred to 301 in that application.

Comment: No common "stainless" steels can be in a marine environment (such as florida) without cover. For that you need specifically (chloride) corrosion resistant steels. more like 314 and 316 and even those can be argued are not sufficient, you'd need the moly-steels. In any case, paints / "coatings" today not only have weight, they also support the structure, in some cases quite substantially.

Comment: @Uwe stainless definitely can rust happens in rifle barrels all the time, high quality 416r

Comment: @OrganicMarble Just a thought, but consider adding that, and your reference, to the Wikipedia page. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(rocket_family)#SM-65_Atlas_missile