# Why the Snoopy Cap rather than a conventional headset?

Tags: astronauts, spacesuits, equipment

Why do American astronauts wear the "snoopy cap" elastic hood with communications headset rather than a more conventional style of headset that doesn't have a hood? Does the cap provide functions other than holding the comms microphone and earphones?

Comment: If your conventional headset got displaced inside your helmet, there is no way to fix that without doffing your helmet.

Comment: The [Russians](https://www.howdoibecomea.net/greatest-soviet-cosmonauts-in-history/) (& the Chinese) still have their version of the [Snoopy cap](https://cdn-japantimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/n-astronautexam-a-20150509.jpg).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoopy_cap

Comment: "Why not a conventional headset?" is easily answered by the requirements, namely weight and reliability.  A complete redesign based just on weight likely pays for itself many times over.  After you realize that, the question is better formulated as "Why would you expect it to look like a conventional headset?".

Comment: Other than self-tapping wood screws I can't think of a better way to keep the headset in place inside a helmet, and I'm not sure screws would be as comfortable.

Comment: @GdD there's always the tried and true duct tape approach https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38845/6944

Comment: It takes a hardy soul to duct tape a headphone to one's skin @OrganicMarble.